# Regex to extract string between parentheses which also contains other parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, string, perl

I've been trying to figure this out, but I don't think I understand Regex well enough to get to where I need to.

I have string that resemble these:

```
filename.txt(1)attribute, 2)attribute(s), more!)
otherfile.txt(abc, def)
```

Basically, a string that always starts with a filename, then has some text between parentheses. And I'm trying to extract that part which is between the main parentheses, but the text that's there can contain absolutely anything, even some more parentheses (it often does.)

Originally, there was a 'hacky' expression made like this:

```
/\(([^@]+)\)\g
```

And it worked, until we ran into a case where the input string contained a @ and we were stuck. Obviously...

I can't change the way the strings are generated, it's always a filename, then some parentheses and something of unknown length and content inside.

I'm hoping for a simple Regex expression, since I need this to work in both C# and in Perl -- is such a thing possible? Or does this require something more complex, like its own parsing method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change exception for `@` symbol in your regex to regex matches any characters and add quantifier that matches from 0 to infinity symbols. And also simplify your regex by deleting group construction:

```
\(.*\)
```

Here is the explanation for the regular expression:

- Symbol `\(` matches the character `(` literally.
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*` quantifier matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times
  as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\)` matches the character `)` literally.

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to compose and debug your regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was so easy... I was on that site to test for expressions and I'd been trying things for well over an hour now. Clearly I need to go read a book about Regex, eh? EDIT: Hang on, this doesn't remove the main parentheses though - I'm really looking for only the contents, not everything after filename, that's too easy. ;)

Comment: OK, so after more tweaking, I ended up with `\((.*)\)` which seems to meet all the requirements. So far, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regex seems overkill to me in this case. Can be more reliably achieved using `string` manipulation methods.

```
int first = str.IndexOf("(");
int last = str.LastIndexOf(")");
if (first != -1 && last != -1)
{
    string subString = str.Substring(first + 1, last - first - 1);
}
```

I've never used Perl, but I'll venture a guess that it has equivalent methods.

Comment: It'll be good to check `first` and `last` variables for boundary scenarios.

Comment: I expect this would totally have been easier, yes. I guess I first thought of doing it with Regex because the original code (not mine) was that way?

Comment: @Rotem, there are several reasons not to use Regexes, performance would be one, unfamiliarity or being scared another reason. And probably a dozen more. About the first, micro optimisation here is not something to concern about, unless we need to deel with massive amounts of strings and every nano second counts. I'd suggest do C or assembler. Unfamiliarity is what i would call a challenge, for every developer. ---- However, code clarity is a very good reason to do use regex, especially here. compare your 6 lines with this 1: `my ($substring) = $str =~ / \( (.*) \) /x ;` that is the Perl way!

Comment: @vanHoesel The Perl way is golfed unreadable code? Glad I don't write Perl ;)

Comment: You are saying ... you can not understand that the result of the 'binding match' operation `=~`, that could have multiple matches if we had multiple capturing parenthesis `(` ... `)`, that it would assign that result to a list of variables `( $substring , )` which happened to be only 1 and discard the remaining? You will learn quick enough that `$count = $str =~ / \( (.*) \) /x;` does give you the number of matches and *not* the first and only matched captured string. And be honest, that was just a simple 1 line of code --- I was not talking about Perl golf 'oneliners' - those are horrifying!

Comment: I am saying, or trying to say, that I don't measure clarity or readability by number of lines of code, but by how long is the sentence in your head that you need to construct in order to explain to yourself what the code you are looking at does. I could golf my code to one line, but I doubt it would make it any more readable. Having said that, I don't use Perl at all and rarely have to use Regex in my work, so I am not in a place to make an objective apples to apples comparison.